# What happens when certificates created by Acrobat expire?

Tags: pdf, ssl, certificate, adobe-acrobat

If I create a certificate using Adobe Acrobat to encrypt PDFs, I notice that the certificate has an expiration date (5 years after its creation date) when looking them up on Certmgr.

My question is, what happens once this date passes. Will the documents no longer be viewable?

Comment: Try putting your computer clock forward 5 years and see what happens.

Comment: You continue to trust it since you created the certificate and I presume you trust something you created.  Expired certificates don't mean a great deal, they only expired honestly, to keep people from using the same (insecure) certificate forever ( i.e. from keeping everyone from using SHA-1 certificates instead of migrating to SHA-2 certificates).